# python nltk processing with text, remove stopwords quickly

Tags: python, text, nltk

I'm using nltk for processing text data. When I want to use stopwords, I usually use this code.

```
text_clean = [w for w in text if w.lower() not in stopwords]
```

But this code always takes too long.(Maybe my data is too big...)
Is there any method to reduce the time? Thanks.

Comment: stopwords is a set or a list?

Comment: I'm sorry, it is list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try converting `stopwords` to a set. Using a list, your approach is `O(n*m)` where n is the number of words in text and `m` is the number of stop-words, using a `set` the approach is `O(n + m)`. Let's compare both approaches `list` vs `set`:

```
import timeit
from nltk.corpus import stopwords


def list_clean(text):
    stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
    return [w for w in text if w.lower() not in stop_words]


def set_clean(text):
    set_stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
    return [w for w in text if w.lower() not in set_stop_words]

text = ['the', 'cat', 'is', 'on', 'the', 'table', 'that', 'is', 'in', 'some', 'room'] * 100000

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(timeit.timeit('list_clean(text)', 'from __main__ import text,list_clean', number=5))
    print(timeit.timeit('set_clean(text)', 'from __main__ import text,set_clean', number=5))
```

**Output**

```
7.6629380420199595
0.8327891009976156
```

In the code above `list_clean` is a function that removes stopwords using a `list` and `set_clean` is a function that removes stopwords using a `set`. The first time corresponds to `list_clean` and the second time corresponds to `set_clean`. For the given example the `set_clean` is almost 10 times faster.

**UPDATE**

The `O(n*m)` and `O(n + m)` are examples of [big o notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), a theoretical approach of measuring the efficiency of algorithms. Basically the larger the polynomial the less efficient the algorithm, in this case `O(n*m)` is larger than `O(n + m)` so the `list_clean` method is theoretically less efficient than the `set_clean` method. This numbers come from the fact that search in list is `O(n)` and searching in a `set` takes a constant amount of time, often referred as `O(1)`.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't understand 0(n*m) and o(n+m) mean. Could you tell me what it is?

Comment: I updated the answer.